# powershell get-service -forgroundcolor

Tags: powershell

I am trying to change the color of my get-service output. It does not seem to allow me to use the write-host -forgroundcolor parameter after get-service. Is there any way around this?

I have tried the following configurations:

```
get-service write-host -foregroundcolor "green"
get-service -foregroundcolor "green"
```

I can get it to kind of work if I save get-service into a variable and place write-host in front like so:

```
$var = get-service

write-host $var -foregroundcolor "green"
```

The problem with this is the output is not formatted correct and becomes a single line.

Comment: `Get-Service | Out-String -Stream | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green`

Comment: You can pipe the output of `Get-Service` to `Write-Host`; however, the default output format gives the status, name, and friendly-name of the services, whereas `Write-Host` will only use the name.

Comment: @PetSerAl - Propose that as an answer, not merely as a comment. You might also want to explain what it does and why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Get-Service | Out-String [-Stream] | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green
```

According to `Out-String`'s help topic:

```
The Out-String cmdlet converts the objects that Windows PowerShell manages into an
array of strings. By default, Out-String accumulates the strings and returns them as
a single string, but you can use the stream parameter to direct Out-String to return 
one string at a time. This cmdlet lets you search and manipulate string output as 
you would in traditional shells when object manipulation is less convenient.
```

By using the `-Stream` argument, you don't wait for `Get-Service` to complete execution but it takes inputs as it gets them.

Comment: If you do not use `Out-String -Stream`, then you need to use `Write-Host -NoNewline`, otherwise you will get one extra empty line in the end of output.

Comment: @PetSerAl Wouldn't `-NoNewline` cause it all to come out on one line?

Comment: @PetSerAl Hm, `-NoNewline` with `-Stream` causes the issue I thought would happen, but I get the same output if I have `-Stream` versus `-NoNewline`, so it seems a bit redundant.

Comment: `'Line 1', 'Line 2', 'Line 3' | Out-String -Stream | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green` and `'Line 1', 'Line 2', 'Line 3' | Out-String | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green -NoNewline` will give you the same output, but `'Line 1', 'Line 2', 'Line 3' | Out-String | Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green` will give one extra empty line in the end.

Comment: @PetSerAl Gotcha, thanks for the clarification.  For this purpose, I don't think it's critical, but it's useful to know.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can:

Write-Host -ForegroundColor Green (Get-Service | out-string)